# Unable to cakin_make openni2_camera

Tags: ros, openni2-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using Odroid XU3, with ubuntu 12.04(precise) and ROS(Hydro).
I've got OpenNI2 installed on my Home folder, and I can run openni2_example from odroid-development. But when I catkin_make, there is the error of [package 'libopenni2' not found] and [package 'openni2' not found]. Have you encountered this problem before? Can you suggest a solution for me to fix this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201504/unable-to-cakin_make-openni2_camera./) by [Xin](https://answers.ros.org/users/21449/xin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to isntall libopenni2 -- under ubuntu/debian you should be able to install the package libopenni2-dev if it is build for your platform, otherwise, you will need to build from source, I believe the hydro releases were built from: https://github.com/hcw70/OpenNI2

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2015-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Xin](https://answers.ros.org/users/21449/xin/) on 2015-01-25**:
I tried to install libopenni2-dev but I got this

Package libopenni2-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libopenni2-dev' has no installation candidate